# way to select a div class or id which is dynamically created by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So in my website code, i use jquery to dynamically create div elements, which are basically clones of a template( written HTML in the page, and i am just cloning it depending on data from database). Below I will write the html code I am cloning

```
<div class="list">
div class="menu"> <button class="accordion">Room 1</button>
<div class="panel"> 
    <div class="exhibits">Exhibit 1</div>
    <button id="addnewBtn">Add new Exhibit BTN</button>
```

and the jquery code i use to clone it is this below

```
$(template).clone(true).appendTo('.list');
            $('.accordion').last().attr('id','accordion'+array[i].id);
            $('#accordion'+array[i].id).html("Room"+array[i].id);
```

so what jquery does, is that it clones the above HTMl code and appends it to class='list' then  adds an id, so that i can distinguish each accordion menu, and changed its title. So when there are 4 rooms in my database, you will see Room 1, Room 2, Room 3, Room 4 on the site with ids accordion1,accordion2 etc
the ids are stored in a array, to be used in another function that loads the exhibits inside the rooms

My problem is that I need the website to present the user with some exhibits, based on the room selected. Those exhibits are to be placed in the div class='exhibits' , which is a 'grandchild' of accordion. But i cannot find a way to do that. I found that you can use something like $('#accordion1 #exhibits)(exhibits at the moment is a class, tried it both as a class and an id) and even add '.panel' between them ( a class between those 2 if you check the html) in order to add the data in the right section but the way i am trying to make it work, doesnt work. So below is the code I am currently trying to use to add exhibits to a specific room

```
$('#'+roomcounter[j+1]+' .exhibits').append(('<br>')+array[i].exhibitname+('<button id="addnewBtn">Add new Exhibit BTN</button></br>'));
```

where roomcounter[j+1] is the array which stores the id of the dynamically created accordion. So for example it would show 'accordion1'
But on the website, nothing shows up (all arrays, data stored and retrieved work. tested each one of them)  So any ideas on that matter?

Comment: you can use `$(document).on('click', '.myDynamicClass', function() {})` :)

Comment: A complete example of the minimum amount of code in a paste showing your problem is going to go a long way to getting this answered. I cant tell if you are having a selector problem, or some kind of problem with your javascript right now.

Comment: By the way, `<br> …</br>` looks strange

Comment: The problem is with the selector, because if i just try to just show the exhibitsname in a random div,class, under the accordion list, it works. what doesnt work is when i try to make them show up in the dynamically created accordions. If you check the HTML code, the exhibitsname should show up in `<div class="exhibits">Exhibit 1</div>`
The `<br> ....</br>` is there because There are multiple exhibits in the database, and I want them to be shown in a kind of list, which works fine for me in that way. Even without the `<br>..</br>` i cant get the job done. so that is surely not the problem